# Xcode6 - ibtool failed with exit code 255

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, swift, xcode6

I read all previous answers for this question but nothing helped to me.

I wanted to learn Swift but even empty projects shows this error after build:

> Command /Volumes/Xcode/Xcode6-Beta4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

I use Xcode6-Beta4.

When I try to click Storyboard, Xcode crashes.
Checked my previous applications - same problem with storyboard. But on Xcode5 they work perfectly.

---

What I tried/checked

- I have no special symbols in the name/id/etc.
- Provisioning profile is connected successfully.
- Choosing another device/target in Deployment Info didnt help too
- Clean/Rebuild/Restart/Reboot/Waiting for hour and smoking didnt help.

So I give up and really need your help.

Comment: I had a same problem. But not able to found any solution yet. It may be because of its a beta version.

Comment: I use this Demo project but the same problem [Project link](https://github.com/voyage11/AutoLayoutBasics)

Comment: the project is for ios 7 and 8 so it has .swift class

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing may be this will work for you.

Delete that app from simulator or reset content of your simulator then try to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to change the /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist content back to 10.10, because I'm using OS X Yosemite Public Beta.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Xcode 9 beta and iOS 11 beta.  Deleting the app and then reinstalling fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch simulator and it works!! its an issue from the xCode! you can reset the simulator or switch to another simulator and it will work